# Python MySQLdb can't connect to remote host?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am connecting to another system's MySQL in our local network. This is what I did:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect('192.168.100.30','nvnew','nvnew','disdb')
cur = db.cursor()
```

This is the error I got:

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.100.30' (111)")
```

I have created the user 'nvnew', granted all the privileges, even manually logged in by  that user name to test, so i don't know why the error is coming. I searched google and read all the answers still unable to solve this as everywhere, they show this syntax as correct.

I read somewhere to comment the line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. I did that but still I am getting the same error. Also, while connecting to remote system's mysql from my system's terminal using.

```
mysql -h 192.168.100.30 -u nvnew -p
```

I was unable to get connected to that.

Can you help?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472175/operationalerror-operationalerror-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-1

Comment: Please be kind and give us some feedback. If there was helpful answer you should mark it as accepted and if you've found solution by yourself, please, post it as a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind it to exact IP `192.168.100.30` (guess, it is static address) instead of commenting

```
bind-address = 192.168.100.30
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the remote MySQL daemon after editing the configuration?

(You can use `netstat -ltpn` to find out if it's listening on 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0.)

Also, be sure you understand the implications of having MySQL bind to all addresses instead of 127.0.0.1 only.