# PYMYSQL ERROR 2021(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench, flask-sqlalchemy

My system:

- Windows 10 pro, version 1909 (build 18363.836)
- Anaconda version: conda 4.10.1
- Python 3.8.5 (python in conda env) and Python 3.9
- Jupyter Lab
- VS code

Hi! I hope you guys have a great day.

I have just installed mysql server and mysql workbench on my PC and I have some difficulties when I try to connect my python file to mysql database (I am using mysql workbench as the app) through "sqlalchemy". I have tried using VS code and Jupyter Lab, both of them yield the same result, nothing.

This is the code that I use:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

engine1 = db.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:12345@localhost:3306/sql_store')
con1 = engine1.connect()
meta = db.MetaData()

pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM customers', con1, index_col='customer_id')
```

By the way, I have tried this code on my "Laptop" (not on my "PC") and it works well. I am a newbie in this field, so any suggestion would be fantastic since I have been dealing with this issue for days.

The error that I am getting is this:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: `//user@password@localhost:3306` means "the MySQL server on this machine." It seems likely that the MySQL database on your "PC" rather than your "laptop" has a different root password.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the presence of special characters in your DB password. If that's your case, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69324774/8929855).